# Tool or library to draw bipartite graph?

Tags: java, graph, bipartite

I am working on things related to Graph Theory. Actually I have some data for bipartite graph and I want to test its validity by visualizing in graph form.

My data is in form like (for triangle):

```
V 0 A
V 1 B
V 2 C
U 0 1 E
```

V denotes the vertices and U denotes edges (A, B, C and E are labels).
Can anyone suggest any tool/library (Java/C) best suited for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUNG 2.0 supports bipartite graph in both non-GUI and GUI coding

http://jung.sourceforge.net/applet/southern.html

Answer (score 0):

JGraph is probably what you're looking for.

http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html

Creating a GraphViz file or using Processing might also be options.